# Filter an array of objects by key value into array

Tags: javascript

I have a $scope variable that contains an array of objects.

```
$scope.arrayOfObjects = [{key:"ASS"}, 
{key:"CRT"},{key:"PRD"}]
```

And I have an array with this value

```
var arr = ["ASS", "CRT"]
```

I would update the array of objects with only the value of the keys into that are only in the array. How can do it?

```
$scope.arrayOfObjects = [{key:"ASS"},
{key:"CRT"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var arr = ["ASS", "CRT"];
var objArr = arr.map( _ => ({ key: _ }) );
console.log(objArr);
```

---

### Or maybe

```js
var arrayOfObjects =  [
   {key:"ASS"}, {key:"CRT"}, {key:"PRD"}
];
var arr = ["ASS", "CRT"];
var objArr = arr.map( _ => arrayOfObjects.find( _1 => _1.key == _ ) );
console.log(objArr);
```

Comment: I mean this is absolutely what I would do but why are you using `_` as the variable name? This could be really confusing especially to some beginners. Is there any reason or just personal preference (tight code)?

Comment: In the Scala language underscore (`_`) is used regularly in specifying the parameter of a function literal. Other people commonly use it in JavaScript. It is a matter of personal preference and style.